# How to run python code that includes print statements without printing? A silent mode

Tags: python, printing, disable

I'm running a neural network from KERAS, which prints a lot when running. I want to run this code with print disabled. I read on stackoverflow that ";" did that, but it doesn't work all the time, and I can't find a place to read about it.

What can you write so that printing is disabled?

I want to run this function with prints disabled:

```
def neural_network():
callback =tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss",min_delta=0,patience=50,verbose=0,mode="auto",baseline=None,restore_best_weights=True,)
model = Sequential()


model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu', input_shape = (30,))) #activation funktionen er også en hyperparameter

model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

# Compile the model.
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.0005)
model.compile(
  optimizer=adam,
  loss="binary_crossentropy", #mean_absolute_error
  metrics=['accuracy'], #ændr metric
)

# Train the model.
model.fit(
  train_u_x, #training data
  train_u_y, #training targets
  epochs=50,
  validation_data = (val_u_x, val_u_y),
  batch_size=32,
  callbacks=[callback]
)

#Testig the NN on the test-data
score=model.evaluate(test_u_x, test_u_y, verbose=2)

loss_list.append(score[0])
accuracy_list.append(score[1])
```

Comment: Try adding `verbose=0`

Comment: There it is! model.fit takes a verbose variable that is automatically set to 1, but setting it to 0 disables printing!

Comment: I was actually looking for a general purpose solution in python, because I thought there must be one, but this works too. Thank you

Comment: Np.  Hopefully someone will come along and enlighten us on that one!

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import contextlib
with open(os.devnull, "w") as file:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
        <whatever code you want>
```

This essentially redirects all standard output to /dev/null.  `contextlib.redirect_stderr` also exists.